# How to completely disable the display on a MacBook Pro while external monitors are plugged in?

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, macbook, external-display

1. I don't have external keyboard.
2. I use one or two external monitors.
3. I want my MacBook Pro  screen to be disabled when external monitors are connected automatically to save power and fix annoying desktop navigation issues.
4. Dimming the lights is not enough.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

use this application to enable/disable easyli one display under catalina

https://github.com/epalzeolithe/DisableMonitor-3.0